# Is it possible to identify a circular arc given its length and two of its endpoints?

Tags: geometry, circles, arc-length

[image]

Suppose you have the length of the circular arc AB, in addition to the coordinates of A and B. Is this information sufficient to draw the arc (i.e. find its center point)?

Comment: Only if the arc length is equal to the distance between the two points. In that case the arc is the straight line segment connecting the two points.

Comment: Is it given that the arc is of a circle?

Comment: Yes, the arc is a circular arc. I will edit accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, I also have the coordinates of A and B, not only the distance between them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is sufficient except for an ambiguity of which side of the line segment $AB$ the center lies on.  The center lies on the bisector of $AB$.  If $r$ is the radius of the circle, $L$ is the length of the arc, $\theta$ is the angle at the center subtended by $AB$, $d$ is the length of $AB$ we have $$L=r\theta\\d=2r\sin\left (\frac \theta 2\right)$$ and we can solve these numerically to get $r, \theta$.  This lets you find possible points for the center.

A figure is below.  My $B,C$ are your $A,B$.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, may you explain where you got the formula from?

Comment: Draw the figure with the center of the circle, the two radii to $A,B$, and the line from the center to the midpoint of $AB$.  You form two right triangles, which is where the sine comes from.  I added a figure